# Issue in conversions from force to mass units

Tags: forces, mass, dimensional-analysis, weight, unit-conversion

I have a problem converting force to mass units, in this example for `9.81kgf`:

- To get the mass, dividing by gravity, I get `1kg` of mass.
- If I want to convert to `Newtons` first, I have to multiply by `9.81N`, then divide by `9.81m/s^2`; finally I get `9.81kg` of mass.

The results are different, what have I done wrong? I don't get it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion mass between mass units](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/432682/)

Comment: I don't have answers. Sorry, but this is more specific.

Comment: 9.81 kgf is already 9.81 N.

Comment: But, for definition 1 kgf = 9.81 N.

Comment: @Isai I think 9.81kgf means the gravitational pull experienced by a mass of 9.8 kg(weight of 9.8 kg mass).So the mass is 9.8 kg.Multiply it by 9.8 to get weight.

Comment: @Isai, there is no SI unit for kgf, and there is no conversion factor for it.  Mass is kg.  Force is Newtons.  I suggest you carefully read chapter 1 of practically any high school physics book.

Answer (score 2):

One $kgf$ is the force produced by one kilogram at the Earth's surface, that is when the gravitational acceleration is $g$, so $9.81 kgf$ is the force produced by $9.81$ kilograms.

You say:

> To get the mass, dividing by gravity, I get 1kg of mass

and you are correct that you need to divide by the gravitational acceleration, but you have to keep your units consistent. If your unit of force is *kgf* then the unit of acceleration is $kgf/kg$ and that means in these units $g=1$. So the mass corresponding to $9.81~kgf$ is $9.81/1 = 9.81$ kg.